# How to assign different fragment to different colortab?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, github-pages, android-tablayout

I am using this [ColorMatchTabsAndroid](https://github.com/Yalantis/ColorMatchTabsAndroid)

How to assign separate fragment for each tab? [Here](https://github.com/Yalantis/ColorMatchTabsAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yalantis/colormatchtabs/colortabs/ColorTabsAdapter.kt)

I have succeeded adding

```
adapter.addFragment(new DashboardTabs(), "Home");
```

Is this the correct way? Vecause I am facing unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Please post your codes, and errors. Not just links.

Comment: no idea how to post code here

Comment: For the time being my code is here https://github.com/Yalantis/ColorMatchTabsAndroid/issues/5

Comment: those who are looking for the same ,, i have included switch case in adapter

@override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
switch (position) {
case 0:
return new FragmentHome();
case 1:
return new FragmentAlbums();
case 2:
return new FragmentArtist();
case 3:
return new FragmentCategories();
default:
// This should never happen. Always account for each position above
return null;
}

}